# Why am I getting incorrect driver classes in SCCM with my PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, driver, sccm

SCCM Version: 2012 R2
PowerShell Version: 3
Operating System: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

I've written a script to create driver packs in SCCM using only signed hard drive controller (HDC) and network (NET) driver classes but I'm getting all sorts of drivers showing up in SCCM.

[image: problem description]

I'm hoping this is not posted the wrong place as this issue will require knowledge of both SCCM and PowerShell.

Here is the script:

```
#Vars
$site = "SITENAME:"
$configMgrCmdLets = "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1"
$DriverPackagePath = "\\ServerName\sources\DriverPacks\PE\SignedBootDrivers"
$DriverPackageName = "Signed Boot Drivers"
$MaxQueryResults = 4000

#pre-reqs
Import-Module $configMgrCmdLets

Set-Location $site
if (get-cmSite)
{
    #all good, let's proceed.
    Set-CMQueryResultMaximum -Maximum $MaxQueryResults

    #Does the driverpackage already exist? If not, Create it.
    if (!(Get-cmDriverPackage -Name $DriverPackageName))
    {
        New-CMDriverPackage -Name $DriverPackageName -Path $DriverPackagePath -PackageSourceType StorageDirect
    }


    $drivers = Get-CMDriver | Where-Object `
    {
        $_.IsSuperseded -eq $false `
            -and $_.IsEnabled -eq $true `
            -and $_.IsHidden -eq $false `
            -and $_.DriverSigned -eq $true `
            -and ($_.DriverClass -eq "hdc" -or $_.DriverClass -eq "net") `
            -and $_.SDMPackageXML -match "x64 Windows 8"
    }

    ForEach ($driver in $drivers)
    {
        Add-CMDriverToDriverPackage -Driver $driver -DriverPackageName $DriverPackageName

        #Output the driver class so that I can verify the result is HDC or NET.
        $driver.DriverClass
    }


}
    else
    {
        Write-Error -Message "Can't read Site: $site. Perhaps the SCCM CmdLets were not imported?"
    }
```

As you can see at one point in the script I output the driver class so that I can manually verify the output to the driver pack and all that is output is hdc or net driver classes.

[image: driver class output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see there is nothing wrong with your script. I am working on a similar solution but I get the same result as you. The output list looks good but when adding the drivers to a package I get all sort of other drivers no matter what I do. The only thing common to the drivers I want to add (only hdc in my case) and the rest of the of the drivers added is the source path. If you bring up the "Content Source Path" column in the console you you can see that the hdc driver has the same source path as the other drivers added. So my conclusion is that Add-CMDriverToDriverPackage adds all driver in the same location regardless of the one specified in your search string.

I think it's a flaw in the design of the cmdlet, it even says so in the description on Technet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj850173(v=sc.20).aspx "*When a device driver is added to a driver package, Microsoft System Center 2012 Configuration Manager copies the device driver content from the driver source location to the driver package.*"

Answer (score 0):

First things first, remove all drivers from the driver package and try this script again.  I'll bet at some point you may have accidentally added some drivers to this package, hence this confusion, because otherwise your script looks sound.

If this doesn't work, I would then troubleshoot at this point in your script:

```
$drivers = Get-CMDriver | Where-Object `
{
    $_.IsSuperseded -eq $false `
        -and $_.IsEnabled -eq $true `
        -and $_.IsHidden -eq $false `
        -and $_.DriverSigned -eq $true `
        -and ($_.DriverClass -eq "hdc" -or $_.DriverClass -eq "net") `
        -and $_.SDMPackageXML -match "x64 Windows 8"
}
```

Add in a Write-Debug step and choose 'Suspend' when the PowerShell debug prompt appears.  You can then easily troubleshoot which drivers are returned within `$drivers`.

If I had to guess, I would say that perhaps the filter isn't working as desired (gotta watch out for those -or statements when inside of a larger -and statement, very tricky things can happen).  A potential fix would be to move the `-and ($_.DriverClass -eq "hdc" -or $_.DriverClass -eq "net")`statement to be the last statement in your Where-Object filter.

Comment: I have adjusted the section you suggested to put the or statement on the last line. I have troubleshooted this section individually though by just opening the $drivers variable and seeing what it contains. It claims it contains only HDC and NET driver classes.

I have also made to to remove the driver package contents between tries and even gone to the folder location and ensured there are no drivers left in there. I have also tried creating new driver packages just in case but the same issue occurs.